# Quartz Composer View in Xcode

Tags: xcode, graphics

Whenever I add a Quartz Composer View into an Xcode application, the application fails to build. All I do is create a new project, add quartz.framework and then in the main menu.xib I add a quartz composer view. I do nothing else, but the application fails. It gives me the error **The Document "MainMenu.xib" could not be opened. The operation couldn't be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)** I am running OSX 10.9 and Xcode version 5.0.2. Any help as to why the application fails to build is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in how Xcode compiles xib files.  If you haven't already, could you file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com?  Also, what happens if you try to create the `QCView` programmatically?

Comment: Did you file a bug report? Could you link it? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Definitely a bug in Xcode. However if you drill down into the Quartz.framework you will still find the QuartzComposer.framework present. Add that to your project, and somewhere in your code (awakeFromNib worked for my case) add code that looks something like this. You will also have to add your .qtz view to your project so it shows up in your bundle.

```
NSView *superview = [mVisualizerWindow contentView];
NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 400, 400);
mVisualizer = [[QCView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[superview addSubview:mVisualizer];

[mVisualizer unloadComposition];
[mVisualizer loadCompositionFromFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UI Mk.5" ofType:@"qtz"]];
[mVisualizer setMaxRenderingFrameRate: 30.0];
[mVisualizer startRendering];
```

Comment: Could you add Swift version, please?

Answer (score 0):

Swift version could be (in the view controller):

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    let r = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 400, 400)
    let w = QCView(frame: r)
    self.view.addSubview(w)
    w.unloadComposition()
    let p = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "QTTest", ofType: "qtz")
    w.loadComposition(fromFile: p)
    w.startRendering()
}
```